# Simple Oracle UPDATE Statement unusually bad performance

Tags: oracle, performance

every month I do a simple update statement on my oracle database. But, since monday it takes very long. The table grows every month by 5 percent. Now there are 8 million records stored.

The Statement:

```
update /*+ parallel(destination_tab, 4) */ destination_tab dest    
   set (full_name, state) =   
       (select /*+ parallel(source_tab, 4) */ dest.name, src.state   
        from source_tab src   
        where src.city = dest.city);
```

In real there are 20 fields to update, not only two... but so it looks easier to descripe the problem.

explain plan:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                               
| Id  | Operation                    | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |                                   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                               
|   0 | update statement             |                      |  8517K|  3167M|   579M (50)|999:59:59 |                                   
|   1 |  update                      | destination_tab      |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   PX COORDINATOR             |                      |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    PX SEND QC (RANDOM)       | :TQ10000             |  8517K|  3167M|  6198   (1)| 00:01:27 |
|   4 |     px block iterator        |                      |  8517K|  3167M|  6198   (1)| 00:01:27 |
|   5 |      table access full       | DESTINATION_TAB      |  8517K|  3167M|  6198   (1)| 00:01:27 |
|   6 |   table access by index rowid| SOURCE_TAB           |     1 |    56 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |    index unique scan         | CITY_PK              |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Could anyone descripe to me, how this can be? The plan looks very bad! Thank you very very much.

Comment: Why would you do this?  Every month you update every one of your 8 million rows?  That will never be quick, and is surely unnecessary.  Once you have updated a row does it really need updating again every month?  If you want all rows to have up-to-date source info why not just select it from source_tab (join) when you want to see it and don't copy it to destination_tab at all?

Comment: When you say the plan "looks very bad" I'm guessing you mean the full table access on DESTINATION_TAB?  Wrong, that is good!

Comment: How many rows (approx) do you have in the source table? (Does it have stats?)

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. Yes I must do an update on all 8 million records every month. It is an big data warehouse and for 3 years nothing happens. Since monday, the statement has a problem. Yes the full table scan is okay and I have to do this but why need the step "0" in the plan so much cost? In the source table are 500 rows with index.

Comment: Shoud I use a merge-update statement?

Comment: Silly comment, perhaps: is 'destiniation' in your `/*+ parallel(destiniation_tab, 4) */` hint a typo for 'destination'?

Comment: "for 3 years nothing happens. Since monday, the statement has a problem."  So what happened on Sunday?

Comment: I run the update one times a month. For example last mondey. For this reason the next run should be in 3 weeks

Comment: Your TIME is unusually high.  TIME normally doesn't matter, but a value that high implies you are hitting a statistics bug, specifically 9842771.  Check `select * from sys.aux_stats$ where pname in ('SREADTIM', 'MREADTIM');`  Those should be the time for single and multi-block reads, in milliseconds.  Sometimes Oracle thinks that reading a single block will take over a minute(!), and that can throw off plans.  Gathering system statistics can sometimes cause this bug to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say how long is too long.  You are joining an 8 million row table.  Not sure how many rows are in source_tab.

I noticed the execution plan indicates a full table scan of destination_tab.  Is the city column on the destination_tab table indexed?  If not, try adding an index.  If it is, Oracle may be ignoring it because it knows it needs to return every value anyway and destination_tab is the driving table.

No matter how you optimize it, this will always degrade in performance as the tables grow because you are updating every row by fetching a value from the same table joined to another.  That is, you are always doing N operations where N is the number of rows in destination_tab.

High-level questions/suggestions:

1. Do you need to update every row every time?  Are only certain rows likely to have changed values?  If so, can you somehow predict which rows you need to update and limit your updates to it.
2. Why are the hints there?  If performance changes, I would experiment with dropping hints.  It's the optimizer's job to find the best plan for you.  By using hints, you are telling the optimizer how to do its job.  You'd better be right.
3. You are updating the full_name column on destination_tab to the name column of the same row.  But you are obtaining the name column through a join to the table.  It may be quicker to take that out of your select and use something like below.  This is a guess.  It may not matter.

   ```
   update destination_tab dest    
    set full_name = name,
      state = 
      (select src.state   
       from source_tab src   
       where src.city = dest.city);
   ```

Comment: While I generally agree with avoiding hints and letting the optimizer do its job, parallel hints are a little different.  Although they tell the optimizer what to do, they also provide useful information.  Parallel hints are a way of telling the optimizer which statements are more important and should use more than their fair share of resources.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a data warehouse, I wouldn't do updates, especially not every row in a large table.  I'd probably create a [materialized view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28326/repmview.htm) combining the pieces from various base tables, and do a full refresh when needed (non-atomic: truncate + insert append).

Edit:
As for WHY the current update approach is taking much longer than usual, my *guess* is that in previous runs Oracle found a good number of blocks needed for the update in buffer cache, and lately Oracle has had to pull a lot from disk into buffer first.  You can look into consistent gets and db block gets (logical io) vs physical io (disk).

Comment: alter session set sql_trace=true, and examine the output using tkprof.  Good into here: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-trace-10046-trcsess-and-tkprof.php

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

```
merge
 into destination_tab d
using source_tab      s
   on (d.city = d.city)
when matched then
   update 
      set d.state = s.state
    where decode(d.state, s.state, 1, 0) = 0;
```

Comment: +1 Good idea.  It might be worth explaining that MERGE can sometimes out-perform UPDATE because MERGE can use a hash join.

Comment: @Twixt3245  Also, if you want to run this in parallel, don't forget to run `alter session enable parallel dml;`.  And if you're using 11gR2, use statement-level parallelism with something like `merge /*+ parallel(4) */` - then you don't need to specify the objects.  The original example has the table name misspelled, and shouldn't have used parallelism.

Comment: yeah I wrote the statement and have done an error. sorry. In real, the table name is spelled right. The explained plan shows this.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the comments about the sense of a data warehouse and so on. However, I have to do this update in this kind. The update is part of an ETL workflow. I have to copy every month the complete 8 million records of the table "destination". After this step I have to do the UPDATE which makes problems.

I do not understand the problem, that the performance is so bad day-to-day. Usually, the update runs 45 minutes. Now, it runs about 4 hours. But why? There is no sorting necessary, so the famous reason "sorting on disc instead on main memory" is not possible. What is the problem in my case?

Could there be an difference about the performance between normal update (how I do it) and the merge-update?

Comment: Do you know what the query plan looked like before you had the issue? I guess not.

Comment: no sorry but I mean the plan looks good. full table access on destination_tab is okay because I want to update each record. To search record on source_tab oracle uses the index. I don't know what the the problem is.

Comment: Possibly you had a better query plan before... but you'll never know what it was. Anyway there are a lot of other suggestion for you to try. I would suggest try each suggestion and take note of the query plan. If it's no different there will be difference to performance (unless there is a periodic hardware bottleneck clouding the issue)

Comment: Is it theoretically possible, that the blocks on disc are random access instead of sequential read because of a high fragmentation of the disc? Or is this not relevant for practical issues?

Comment: It would be strange for it to have an issue overnight due to that reason. To me it points at the query plan suddenly changing. But performance is a function of many things including query plan and hardware so that hardware could be contributing. Without a baseline you don't know what changed and you don't know where to start looking. Why don't you try some of the suggestions already posted and post back.